Unable to install NTP
I've spent the afternoon attempting to update my PiHole instance, with a complete lack of success. In general, the Pi is unable to resolve external addresses, although it is functioning fine on my network, and appears to be successfully blocking ads. I have worked through a number of different issues with the Pi, and now I am attempting to get the clock set correctly by installing NTP. The symptoms I'm seeing are similar to what I get trying to update PiHole (in that case, it cannot resolve GitHub.com). After a lot of digging around, one possible solution is that the system clock is too far out of sync. In fact the clock is about 3 1/2 hours off, hence my attempt to install NTP. My results:
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo apt install ntp
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libevent-core-2.1-6 libevent-pthreads-2.1-6 libopts25 sntp
Suggested packages:
  ntp-doc
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libevent-core-2.1-6 libevent-pthreads-2.1-6 libopts25 ntp sntp
0 upgraded, 5 newly installed, 0 to remove and 9 not upgraded.
Need to get 1,081 kB of archives.
After this operation, 2,617 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Err:1 http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian buster/main armhf libevent-core-2.1-6 armhf 2.1.8-stable-4
  Temporary failure resolving 'raspbian.raspberrypi.org'
Err:2 http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian buster/main armhf libevent-pthreads-2.1-6 armhf 2.1.8-stable-4
  Temporary failure resolving 'raspbian.raspberrypi.org'
Err:3 http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian buster/main armhf libopts25 armhf 1:5.18.12-4
  Temporary failure resolving 'raspbian.raspberrypi.org'
Err:4 http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian buster/main armhf ntp armhf 1:4.2.8p12+dfsg-4
  Temporary failure resolving 'raspbian.raspberrypi.org'
Err:5 http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian buster/main armhf sntp armhf 1:4.2.8p12+dfsg-4
  Temporary failure resolving 'raspbian.raspberrypi.org'
E: Failed to fetch http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/pool/main/libe/libevent/libevent-core-2.1-6_2.1.8-stable-4_armhf.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'raspbian.raspberrypi.org'
E: Failed to fetch http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/pool/main/libe/libevent/libevent-pthreads-2.1-6_2.1.8-stable-4_armhf.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'raspbian.raspberrypi.org'
E: Failed to fetch http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/pool/main/a/autogen/libopts25_5.18.12-4_armhf.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'raspbian.raspberrypi.org'
E: Failed to fetch http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/pool/main/n/ntp/ntp_4.2.8p12+dfsg-4_armhf.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'raspbian.raspberrypi.org'
E: Failed to fetch http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/pool/main/n/ntp/sntp_4.2.8p12+dfsg-4_armhf.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'raspbian.raspberrypi.org'
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
p


I am a long-term Windows user, but I have only a casual knowledge of Linux. My google-fu has failed me, and I don't know how to proceed. Any suggestions?

Your problem is networking, try another mirror. Installing NTP is unnecessary and only likely to make things worse. It is quite a while since I used Buster and think it may have moved to archive URL

Try ping raspbian.raspberrypi.org.  If that also ends in DNS failure (= "failure resolving"), edit in the contents of /etc/resolv.conf.

@goldilocks: Ping returns Temporary failure in name resolution. The contents of /etc/resolv.conf is nameserver 127.0.0.1. I'm still stuck :(

@Milliways: I don't understand your comment.

Support for older Pi has been moved to archive servers (which don't receive updates); I am not sure of status of Buster. Goldilocks is correct if you can't ping the server (which your question says) NOTHING will work. I normally use local mirrors rather than the resolver which is often slow.


The contents of /etc/resolv.conf is nameserver 127.0.0.1

This means the system is looking for a DNS server running on the local system.   That is not a normal thing to do, and I do not know whether PiHole does or is supposed to do this (it might), but obviously that is not working.  You could check with lsof -i TCP:53 and lsof -i UDP:53.
In any case, you could try adding to that file:
nameserver 1.1.1.1
nameserver 8.8.8.8

These are fast public nameservers (one.com and google) which the system should fall back to when 127.0.0.1 (the local system) fails.  Note that if the lsof check showed nothing, you might as well remove the 127.0.0.1 line.
Some networking software is prone to overwrite /etc/resolv.conf occasionally.  If name resolution fails in the future and you check this file and it has been changed, you can try and make it immutable:
sudo chattr +i /etc/resolv.conf  


OK, so I did this, and then sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade and suddenly @milliways comments were finally understood! Once I changed the repository (definitely not Windows language) using sudo apt-get update --allow-releaseinfo-change I was then able to update my pi successfully, and not have to install NTP as I was fruitlessly attempting to do. Thanks for that assist from both of you.
